# Animation in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

I want to use animation on an Image Button in my fragment what argument
 should I use instead of activity ("this)?

```
pause.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [**`getActivity()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()).

> Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

```
startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
```

Comment: Thank you very much